# create own files_id in mongo GridFs using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

for a better distribution of files in a sharded Mongo GridFs I'd like to create my own files_id. How this can be done in Java is described here:

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/msg/524bae1602770587

But how to do this in PHP? I could find no hint in the API documentation, I use storeBytes for saving the files:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongogridfs.storebytes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just set this in the "$extra" argument with the "_id" key, something like:

```
$m = new Mongo;
$db = $m->phpunit;
$grid = $db->GetGridFS();
$grid->storeBytes("testing", array("_id" => "MYID", "filename" => "test.txt"));
```

cheers,
Derick