# Custom _id for GridFS using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

My question is the same as the one below, except that I want to use the java driver to do this.

[create own files_id in mongo GridFs using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907050/create-own-files-id-in-mongo-gridfs-using-php)

The googlegroup link given in above question for Java driver is actually for C# driver. Checking up the Java driver GridFS api, it seems there is no way to set the _id field for the GridFS files collection.

Is there any way to do this with Java driver, it would create lot of unnecessary mess if I have to switch to using some other driver?

Comment: It doesnt look possible currently but is raised as an improvement here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-525 
Would it be possible to tweak your design until this is implemented? e.g. hold a file id in the linked document(s)

Comment: The basic problem I'm trying to solve here is the sharding of GridFS `chunks` collection which is totally dependent on the files_id. If there is a way to add additional fields to `chunks` collection I'm all open to it.

Comment: The jira case above is now fixed, hopefully it will be available in next release. Only if Casbah could quickly integrate the change!

Answer (score 0):

Put method of the GridFSInputFile Class is for adding additional fields to JSON object. So if you add "_id" field which is ObjectId by default, it will override ObjectId.

I have tried the following code on version 2.2.3 and it worked.

```
GridFSInputFile gif = gridfs.createFile(new File("c:\\image.jpg"));
gif.put("_id", 1234567);
gif.save();
```

files collection contains 1234567 as as expected. chunks collection has same value as file_id.